# WFS GetFeature request feature with lat/lng literal

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms, ogc

According to the Geoserver documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo it is preferred to use the WFS GetFeature service over WMS GetFeatureInfo as literally cited:

> The GetFeatureInfo operation requests the spatial and attribute data for the features at a given location on a map. It is similar to the WFS GetFeature operation, but less flexible in both input and output. Since GeoServer provides a WFS service we recommend using it instead of GetFeatureInfo whenever possible.

I have been looking for a way to request all matching features for a lat/lng point and the shape of a layers geometry via WFS GetFeature. I can't find it and the cql_filter combiantion with `within` or `intersects` won't get me any further. Any good documeantion or examples someone has to share?

Comment: this would be better asked on https://gis.stackexchange.com - but we would want to see examples of what you have tried and what went wrong before we'd be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still needed, but just provides for others who need.

WFS GetFeature request feature with lat/lng literal:

`{youHost}/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName={yourTypeName}&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT ({long} {lat}))`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).